Can I use the I94 that came with my H1B extension for automatic revalidation when I have another I94 issued at the port of entry?
I am in the US on a H1B visa. The current visa stamp expires soon, say on 10 Jul 2024. I have the extension of the H1B approved with start date 11 Jul 2024 and end date of say 10 June 2027 (the H1 approval comes with its own I94).  I understand that if don’t travel my status remains valid till 10 June 2027 (as long as the conditions of the H1B stay valid etc).
I have an upcoming trip to the UK (not my home country, which is India) in May. When I re-enter the US I will show the visa stamp and the new H1 approval to the CBP officer. Based on anecdotal knowledge one of two things can happen.

The officer gives an I94 date of 10 June 2027, matching my extended H1.
The officer gives an I94 date of 10 Jul 2024, matching the visa stamp on the passport.

If 2 happens, my status becomes invalid on 10 Jul 2024 as the latest issued I94 supersedes the older I94. In this case, can I use automatic revalidation to get my status extended? Assuming I have a Canadian tourist visa, if I renter US using automatic revalidation can I show the I94 with my H1 approval for entry? Or should I show the latest issued I94 at the border crossing?
